# Why don't the remember tactics work as documented?

Tags: coq

In an interactive proof, I'm trying to extract an expression into a new variable while capturing the equality as a new proof term.

The [`remember`](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/Reference-Manual010.html#hevea_tactic44) tactic seems designed for this purpose.  Since I like giving explicit names to introduced names, I'd prefer to use this variant:

> 6. remember *term* as *ident* eqn:*ident*
>
> This behaves as `remember term as ident`, except that the name of the generated equality is also given.

However when I attempt it (or the other remember variants), I only get this error:

```
> remember (prefix ++ suffix) as the_environment eqn:H_prefix_suffix.
>                                                ^^^
Syntax error: 'in' '|-' expected after [prim:ident] (in [tactic:simple_tactic]).
```

Heeding the error message, the only variant that actually seems to work is

```
remember (prefix ++ suffix) as the_environment in |-.
```

...which unfortunately doesn't let me choose the name of the introduced proof of equality.

Why don't the documented `remember` variants seem to work?

I'm using coq 8.4pl6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I shot myself in the foot.

I had previously declared a tactic with that syntax:

```
Tactic Notation "remember" constr(c) "as" ident(x) "in" "|-" :=
  let x := fresh x in
  let H := fresh "Heq" x in
  (set (x := c); assert (H : x = c) by reflexivity; clearbody x).
```

It seems this explicit definition masks the built-in variants.  Removing this definition makes the others visible again.